# join columns across multiple lines in a Text based on common column using BASH

Tags: bash, parsing, text, dynamic-sql

I have a file like below .

```
Table1|Column1
Table2|Column1
Table5|Column1
Table3|Column2
Table2|Column2
Table4|Column3
Table2|Column3
Table2|Column4
Table5|Column4
Table2|Column5
```

From the below file i am trying to generate a Dynamic SQL JOIn if Tablenames in Column1 have same Attributes

```
select * from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.Column1=b.column1 inner join Table5 c on a.Column1=c.column1
```

and

```
select * from Table3 a inner join Table2 b on a.column2 = b.column2
```

..etc till end of file

What is the best way to do it , please advise.

Please note that Same column can appear in more than 2 tables (like upto 20 tables then join will be repeated 19 times)

Comment: how `Table2.Column5` should be joined? seems joins are done by column name, and it seems strange to join table from this description, note that depending on dbms `select *` may fail because of duplicate column names, it's recommended to select specific column with table alias, what about using old syntax `select .. from table1, ..table5 where table1.column1 = table2.column1 ...`

Comment: About Table2.Column5 if there is another TableN with column5 exist then join else ignore it. Basically the tables are all related dump from a specific data model domain and as part of testing i am trying to see whether at least some part of the foreign key, Primary Key join testing can be automated . I am Ok with any of the join syntax as long as it works . If some one can help to pop out atleast the tablenames with same columns I can try to use concatenation and generate rest of the join syntax .@NahuelFouilleul

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. However, I think you should be able to solve the problem using this answer as a stepping stone.

We use GNU `awk` for parsing. For better readability we use a script file `parse.awk` instead of one long command.

```
# parse.awk
{ a[$2][$1] };
END {
    for (col in a) {
        printf "%s", col;
        for (tab in a[col])
            printf "|%s", tab;
        print ""
    }
}
```

When we call the script ...

```
awk -F\| -f parse.awk yourFile
```

... on your example the output is

```
Column1|Table5|Table1|Table2
Column2|Table2|Table3
Column3|Table2|Table4
Column4|Table5|Table2
Column5|Table2
```

From there you should be able to build your SQL commands. You could even adapt `parse.awk` to generate the SQL commands directly.

Comment: thanks , this could help. Can you please confirm the script pasted above is complete . I am getting some syntax errors like below                     awk: parse.awk:2: { a[$2][$1] };
awk: parse.awk:2:        ^ syntax error
awk: parse.awk:6:         for (tab in a[col])
awk: parse.awk:6:                      ^ syntax error  @socowi

Comment: @NaveenVenugopal The script works for me. What is your `awk --version`? Mine is *GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)*.

Comment: awk --version GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: I can reproduce the error with that version, but cannot fix it easily. It seems like that version of `awk` did not support multi-dimensional arrays. Any chance you can update your `awk`? Version 3.1.8 is from the year 2010.

Comment: Thank you @Socowi for going the extra length. Unfortunately this is the server where i need to run the scripts on and I have no control over it .At this point of time i do not know how to retrofit the code with my version of awk.May be some one else might have a better idea.